# Jquery - move element left or right with condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, move

Hello everyone I explain my problem, 
I created a master container 500px wide and 100px high (with overflow hidden) ...

inside a container 2 of various boxes, always 500px 100px, ill' insert a number of boxes 100px X 100px, plus two control buttons to move the container to the right or left of 100px.

The boxes are visible 5, for example, if there are 8 I would like to click the button 'right' container 2 would shift 100px but when they get to the last block (in this example is 8) button to go to right must disable.
Conversely, if we start the button to the left to Go must be disabled until the right has done at least one move.

Also as you can see at the click when I move the elements contained in the box it disappear during movement and this thing is no good, various box must move but always remain visible.

On JSfiddle I created a demo, I can not create the right conditions, you have a solution? thanks

[enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/stormadv/bjutbsje/1/)

```js
$( "#right" ).click(function() {
  $( "#block" ).animate({ "left": "+=105px" }, "slow" );
    
});
 
$( "#left" ).click(function(){
  $( "#block" ).animate({ "left": "-=105px" }, "slow" );
});
```

```css
.cont{
    width:530px;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    background:#000;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.box-cont{
    width:auto;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    background:yellow;
   
}
.box{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin-left:5px;
    background:#F00;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:32px;
}
.btn{

    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:120px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cont">
  
    

    <div class="box-cont" id="block">
        
        <div class="box">1</div>
        <div class="box">2</div>
        <div class="box">3</div>
        <div class="box">4</div>
        <div class="box">5</div>
        <div class="box">6</div>
        <div class="box">7</div>
        <div class="box">8</div>
        
    </div>
    
    
</div>

<div class="btn">
    <button id="left">&laquo;</button>
    <button id="right">&raquo;</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
<script>

    var totalBlocks         = $('#block div.box').length;
    var blockViews          = Math.round($('#block').width() / $('#block div.box').width());
    var currentPosition     = 0;

    $( "#right" ).click(function() {

        if(currentPosition > 0)
        {
            $( "#block" ).animate({ "left": "+=105px" }, "slow" );
            currentPosition--;
        }
    });

    $( "#left" ).click(function(){
        if(blockViews + (currentPosition+1) <= totalBlocks)
        {   
            $( "#block" ).animate({ "left": "-=105px" }, "slow" );
            currentPosition++;
      }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this, does this help? you can drag and move the elements themselves, and put left and right thresholds on them. I was trying to mimic google gmail swipe
http://jsfiddle.net/williamhowley/o9uvo50y/

```
 $('ul#main > li')
.on('movestart', function (e) {
    console.log("move start");

    // var $li = $(e.target).closest('.swipable'); // this would be normal live integration
    var $li = $(e.target);
    if ($li.attr("data-hasplaceholder") !== "true") { // if it does not have a placeholder, add one.
        createBackgroundSpacer($li);
        $li.attr("data-hasplaceholder", true); // signify that a placeholder has been created for this element already. 
    }

    // If the movestart heads off in a upwards or downwards
    // direction, prevent it so that the browser scrolls normally.
    if ((e.distX > e.distY && e.distX < -e.distY) ||
        (e.distX < e.distY && e.distX > -e.distY)) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return;
    }

    // To allow the slide to keep step with the finger,
    // temporarily disable transitions.
    wrap.addClass('notransition'); // add this to the container wrapper. 
})
.on('move', function (e) {
    // event definitions
    // startX : 184, where from left the mouse curser started.
    // deltaX: ?
    // distX: how far the mouse has moved, if negative moving left. Still need to account for double movement, currently can only handle one movement. 

    console.log("move");
    console.log(e);

    var maxLeft = $('.rightContent').width();
    var marginLeftNum = Number($(this).css('margin-left').replace(/[^-\d\.]/g, ''));

    if (marginLeftNum <= -maxLeft && e.deltaX < 0) { // Case when user is at outermost left threshold, and trying to move farther left.  
        $(this).css({ 'margin-left': -maxLeft });
    }
    else if (marginLeftNum == -maxLeft && e.deltaX > 0) { // When user is at threshold, and trying to move back right. 
        $(this).css({ 'margin-left': marginLeftNum + e.deltaX });
    }
    else if (e.target.offsetLeft>=0 && e.deltaX>0) { // If the offset is 0 or more, and the user is scrolling right (which is a positive delta, than limit the element. )
        $(this).css({ 'margin-left': 0 });
    }
     // Must have a Negative offset, and e.deltaX is Negative so it is moving left. 
    else if (e.deltaX < 0) { // Case when element is at 0, and mouse movement is going left. 
        $(this).css({ 'margin-left': marginLeftNum + e.deltaX }); 
    }
    else {  // Moving Right when not on 0
        $(this).css({ 'margin-left': marginLeftNum + e.deltaX });
    }



})
.on('swipeleft', function (e) {
    console.log("swipeleft");
})
.on('activate', function (e) {
    // not seeing this activate go off, i think this is custom function we can add on if swipe left hits a threshold or something. 
    console.log("activate");
})
.on('moveend', function (e) {
    console.log("move end");
    wrap.removeClass('notransition');
 });
```